# LTspice: unexpected current behavior

Tags: circuit, pspice

Driving a power mosfet with a gate driver w/ PWM toggle. When high, mosfet is expected to sink most of the current (current and voltage values in schematic are for testing purposes) through R1, however current does not change in 2nd branch (R3). Can someone explain this behavior?

Thanks.

[image: circuit schematic]

Answer (score 0):

It's just two resistors in parallel when the mosfet is open, so a simple I = V/R.

Answer (score 0):

V3 s an ideal voltage source. The voltage doesn't change with the load. So R3 always will see the same voltage no matter if you switch on or off the MOSFET.
I(R3)=V3/R3